# SQL Server query to solve

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a database where there are multiple company names. I need to make a query that will find: company name, number of entries, date of newest entry.

Preferably order should be by the date of the latest entry (but I can sort that out even in excel)

```
SELECT 
    /*this is the list of companies with distinct name */
    DISTINCT(K.COMPANY) AS company_name,
    /*where I count entries*/
    (SELECT COUNT(KK.COMPANIES) FROM COMPANIES KK 
     WHERE KK.COMPANY = K.company_name) AS company_count,
    /*where I try to get newest entry date*/
    (SELECT TOP 1 ENTRY_DATE FROM COMPANIES KKK 
     WHERE KKK.COMPANY = K.company_name 
     ORDER BY KKK.ENTRY_DATE DESC) AS company_date
FROM 
    COMPANIES K 
WHERE
    K.ENTRY_DATE > '20211004 00:00:00'  
ORDER BY
    K.ID_KAMSOFT DESC
```

I get an error:

> invalid column name

in the subqueries. Basically, the subqueries do not see data from an outer query in the condition `xxx.COMPANY = K.company_name`.

It should be pretty straightforward, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `distinct(K.COMPANY) as company_name`: you cannot use alias in subquery. Change `K.company_name` to `K.company`.

Comment: A COMPANIES table that has multiple rows with the same COMPANY_NAME seems terribly flawed.

Comment: I know, but it must be like this companies are ant really companies -- that is just example :) Thx, for all input

Comment: @Nikola Markovinović - by the way, you solution worked too, I think I will create this quary as second answear just for educationl purpouses.... or maybe you should to this so I could upvote it?

Comment: Thanks mr. Bartek, I just wanted to help you out. I don't do answers anymore, but you might.

Comment: Ok, then. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

You does not need to use a sub query, try a direct `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
    K.COMPANY AS company_name,
    COUNT(1) AS company_count,
    MAX(ENTRY_DATE) AS company_date
FROM 
    COMPANIES K 
WHERE
    K.ENTRY_DATE > '20211004 00:00:00'   
GROUP BY    
    K.COMPANY
ORDER BY
    3 DESC
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. I prefer not to use positions in `ORDER BY`, though. Hence `ORDER BY  company_date DESC`. I also prefer `COUNT(*)` to count rows, because this is the syntax made for this. With `COUNT(1)` you literally tell the DBMS to create a constant 1 per row, check whether that constant is null for the row and if it isn't, count that row. A lot of work, wouldn't SQL Server's optimizer not spot this to be unnecessary. And why 1? Why not `COUNT(123)` or `COUNT('count this row')` or `COUNT('Kermit is a frog')` which would all do the very same thing ;-)

Comment: I  need to confirm data, but this worked flawlessly. i knew there Is easy way to do it :)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner SQL Server has a specific optimization for `COUNT(someconstant)` so I really wouldn't worry

Comment: @Charlieface: I know. But why not just write it properly? `COUNT(*)` is not that harder to type than `COUNT(1)`, and maybe Jayasurya Satheesh didn't know what `COUNT(expression)` is actually made for. Now he knows :-)

Answer (score 1):

The choosen answear is obviously better, but this would work too:

(as @Nikola Markovinović stated, you simply has to use non alias name)

```
SELECT 
    /*this is the list of companies with distinct name */
    DISTINCT(K.COMPANY) AS company_name,
    /*where I count entries*/
    (SELECT COUNT(KK.COMPANIES) FROM COMPANIES KK 
     WHERE KK.COMPANY = K.COMPANY) AS company_count,
    /*where I try to get newest entry date*/
    (SELECT TOP 1 ENTRY_DATE FROM COMPANIES KKK 
     WHERE KKK.COMPANY = K.COMPANY
     ORDER BY KKK.ENTRY_DATE DESC) AS company_date
FROM 
    COMPANIES K 
WHERE
    K.ENTRY_DATE > '20211004 00:00:00'  
ORDER BY
    K.ID_KAMSOFT DESC
```

Comment: Yes this would work and is absolutely horrible. First of all, `DISTINCT(K.COMPANY)` may make it look like `DISTINCT` was a function invoked on `K.COMPANY`, but it isn't. It's a keyword that works on the whole result rows. This means for readability those misleading parentheses should be removed. What the query does is to read every single row in the table and for every row perform the two subqueries. At last it will apply `DISTINCT` and thus probably remove 99 percent of the rows that you so laboriously created.